# Pig: my filter doesn't give result

Tags: hadoop, filter, apache-pig

Hello i am a new comer to hadoop's environmment.
I done request to have data on csv.

```
>LoadHomicide = LOAD '/user/admin/Crimes_samples.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') >AS >(Date:chararray,Block:chararray,PrimaryType:chararray,
>Description:chararray,
>LocationDescription:chararray,Arrest:chararray,Domestic:chararray,District:c>hararray,Year:chararray);

>uniq_arrest = FILTER LoadHomicide BY ($5 matches'%FALSE%');
>dump uniq_arrest;
```

I have nothing as error but the script's log gives answer success csv here.

ID","Case Number","Date","Block","IUCR","Primary Type","Description","Location Description","Arrest","Domestic","Beat","District","Ward","Community Area","FBI Code","X Coordinate","Y Coordinate","Year","Updated On","Latitude","Longitude","Location"

> 0442761,"HZ181379",3/9/16 11:55 PM,"023XX N HAMLIN
>   AVE","0560","ASSAULT","SIMPLE","APARTMENT","false","false","2525","025",35,"22","08A",1150660,1915214,2016,03/16/2016,41.92,-87.72,"(41.923245915,
>   -87.721845939)" 10442848,"HZ181470",3/9/16 11:55 PM,"0000X W JACKSON BLVD","1310","CRIMINAL DAMAGE","TO PROPERTY","CTA GARAGE / OTHER
>   PROPERTY","false","false","0113","001",2,"32","14",1176304,1898987,2016,03/16/2016,41.88,-87.63,"(41.878177799,
>   -87.628111493)" 10442789,"HZ181391",3/9/16 11:55 PM,"052XX W HURON ST","1150","DECEPTIVE PRACTICE","CREDIT CARD
>   FRAUD","ALLEY","false","false","1524","015",28,"25","11",1141433,1904126,2016,03/16/2016,41.89,-87.76,"(41.892994741,
>   -87.756023813)" 10447046,"HZ185157",3/9/16 11:50 PM,"055XX N LINCOLN AVE","0460","BATTERY","SIMPLE","HOTEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matches` syntax is incorrect.Also there is no 6th ($5 refers to 6th field in the schema,positional notation starts from $0) field that has "false" in it.Use the correct field and the right syntax.Assuming 6th field has "false" in it, then this is how you would apply the filter on it.

```
uniq_arrest = FILTER LoadHomicide BY ($5 matches '.*false.*');
```